# Not able to flash aosp 5.0.1 to NEXUS 4 (LG device)

Tags: android

I downloaded lollipop code and build it,

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.0.1_r1
$ repo sync
```

Also downloaded drivers from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#makolrx22c
extracted and its part of vendor folder. 
then below commands I gave build the binaries (is't part of 
/out/target/product/mako)

```
$ lunch aosp_mako-eng
$ make
```

later I flashed

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img 
fastboot flash cache cahche.img
```

Now I am facing problem:
phone is stuck at android logo without any progress,

below is the log:
--------- beginning of main

```
I/kickstart-qcks(    0): PARAMETER VALUES

W/auditd  (  163): type=2000 audit(0.0:1): initialized

I/auditd  (  163): type=1403 audit(0.0:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295

W/auditd  (  163): type=1404 audit(0.0:3): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): COMPORT_DLOAD=/dev/ttyHSL1

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): COMPORT_SAHARA=/dev/ks_hsic_bridge

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): PATHTOIMAGES=/firmware/image/

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): PATHFORRAMDUMP=/data/tombstones/mdm/

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): EFSRAW1=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs1

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): EFSRAW2=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs2

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): EFSRAW3=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs3

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): Header1=efs1.mbn

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): Header2=efs2.mbn

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): Header3=efs3.mbn

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): Testing if port "/dev/mdm" exists

I/kickstart-qcks(    0): Trying to bring MDM9K out of reset

I/lowmemorykiller(  165): Using in-kernel low memory killer interface

E/rmt_storage(  169): Remote storage service is not supported on mdm target

D/QSEECOMD: (  171): qseecom listener services process entry PPID = 1

D/QSEECOMD: (  171): Parent qseecom daemon process paused!! 

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): QSEECOM DAEMON RUNNING 

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): qseecom listener service threads starting!!! 

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Total listener services to start = 2

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Init dlopen(libdrmtime.so, RTLD_NOW) succeeds

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Init::Init dlsym(g_FSHandle atime_start) succeeds

D/QSEECOMAPI: (  189): QSEECom_register_listener 11 sb_length = 0x5000

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Init atime_start ret = 0

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): time services: Started

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Init dlopen(libdrmfs.so, RTLD_NOW) succeeds

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Init::Init dlsym(g_FSHandle fs_start) succeeds

D/QSEECOMAPI: (  189): QSEECom_register_listener 10 sb_length = 0x5000

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): Init fs_start ret = 0

D/QSEECOMD: (  189): file system services: Started

--------- beginning of system

I/Vold    (  167): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): SurfaceFlinger is starting

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...

D/libEGL  (  168): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so

D/libEGL  (  168): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so

D/libEGL  (  168): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so

I/Adreno-EGL(  168): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328

I/qdgralloc(  168): using (fd=13)

I/qdgralloc(  168): id           = msmfb44_80601

I/qdgralloc(  168): xres         = 768 px

I/qdgralloc(  168): yres         = 1280 px

I/qdgralloc(  168): xres_virtual = 768 px

I/qdgralloc(  168): yres_virtual = 3840 px

I/qdgralloc(  168): bpp          = 32

I/qdgralloc(  168): r            = 24:8

I/qdgralloc(  168): g            = 16:8

I/qdgralloc(  168): b            =  8:8

I/qdgralloc(  168): width        = 61 mm (319.790161 dpi)

I/qdgralloc(  168): height       = 102 mm (318.745087 dpi)

I/qdgralloc(  168): refresh rate = 60.00 Hz

D/qdutils (  168): DEBUG_CALC_FPS: 0

D/qdutils (  168): period: 10

D/qdutils (  168): ignorethresh_us: 500000

D/qdutils (  168): DEBUG_CALC_FPS: 0

D/qdutils (  168): period: 10

D/qdutils (  168): ignorethresh_us: 500000

D/qdoverlay(  168): initoverlay:: opening the device:: /dev/graphics/fb0

D/qdoverlay(  168): initoverlay:: opening the device:: /dev/graphics/fb1

D/qdoverlay(  168): initoverlay:: opening the device:: /dev/graphics/fb2

D/qdoverlay(  168): initoverlay:: opening the device:: /dev/graphics/fb0

D/qdoverlay(  168): initoverlay:: opening the device:: /dev/graphics/fb1

D/qdoverlay(  168): initoverlay:: opening the device:: /dev/graphics/fb2

I/qdhwcomposer(  168): Initializing Qualcomm Hardware Composer

I/qdhwcomposer(  168): MDP version: 440

D/qdhwcomposer(  168): connectPPDaemon: CABL is disabled

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): Using composer version 1.2

I/qdhwcomposer(  168): hwc_registerProcs

I/qdhwcomposer(  168): Initializing UEVENT Thread

I/qdhwcomposer(  168): Initializing VSYNC Thread

D/qdhwcomposer(  168): hwc_getDisplayAttributes disp = 0, width = 768

D/qdhwcomposer(  168): hwc_getDisplayAttributes disp = 0, height = 1280

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): EGL information:

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): vendor    : Android

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_lock_surface EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_ANDROID_recordable 

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): Client API: OpenGL_ES

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): EGLSurface: 8-8-8-8, config=0x5

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): OpenGL ES informations:

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): vendor    : Qualcomm

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): renderer  : Adreno (TM) 320

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): version   : OpenGL ES 3.0 V@95.0 AU@  (GIT@Ia6306ec328)

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): extensions: GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_con

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096

I/SurfaceFlinger(  168): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096

D/SurfaceFlinger(  168): Set power mode=2, type=0 flinger=0xb7ddf550

D/libEGL  (  211): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so

D/libEGL  (  211): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so

D/libEGL  (  211): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so

I/Adreno-EGL(  211): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328

D/SurfaceFlinger(  168): shader cache generated - 24 shaders in 299.482391 ms

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): EFS Prepend

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): File:'/firmware/image/efs1.mbn' is available for reading

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): File:'/firmware/image/efs2.mbn' is available for reading

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): File:'/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs1' is available for reading

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): File:'/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs2' is available for reading

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): File:'/firmware/image/acdb.mbn' is available for reading

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): File:'/firmware/image/mdm_acdb.img' is available for reading

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Reading RAW EFS1 partition

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs1 of=/data/qcks/temp.dump bs=1024 count=3072

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Combining Header1 with RAW EFS1 partition

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running cat /firmware/image/efs1.mbn /data/qcks/temp.dump > /data/qcks/efs1.bin

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Reading RAW EFS2 partition

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs2 of=/data/qcks/temp.dump bs=1024 count=3072

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Combining Header2 with RAW EFS2 partition

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running cat /firmware/image/efs2.mbn /data/qcks/temp.dump > /data/qcks/efs2.bin

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Reading RAW EFS3 partition

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs3 of=/data/qcks/temp.dump bs=1024 count=3072

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Combining Header3 with RAW EFS3 partition

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running cat /firmware/image/efs3.mbn /data/qcks/temp.dump > /data/qcks/efs3.bin

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Combining ACDB Header with ACDB binary

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Running cat /firmware/image/acdb.mbn /firmware/image/mdm_acdb.img > /data/qcks/acdb.bin

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Loading Sahara images

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): Testing if port "/dev/ks_hsic_bridge" exists

E/kickstart-qcks(  170): RUNNING:   /system/bin/ks  -w /data/tombstones/mdm/ -p /dev/ks_hsic_bridge -r 21 -s 2:/firmware/image/amss.mbn -s 6:/firmware/image/apps.mbn -s 8:/firmware/image/dsp1.mbn -s 11:/firmware/image/osbl.mbn -s 12:/firmware/image/dsp2.mbn -s 21:/firmware/image/sbl1.mbn -s 22:/firmware/image/sbl2.mbn -s 23:/firmware/image/rpm.mbn -s 28:/firmware/image/dsp3.mbn -s 16:/data/qcks/efs1.bin -s 17:/data/qcks/efs2.bin -s 20:/data/qcks/efs3.bin -s 29:/data/qcks/acdb.bin

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 21, file "/firmware/image/sbl1.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 117700 bytes transferred in 0.124s (0.91 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 23, file "/firmware/image/rpm.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 105696 bytes transferred in 0.024s (4.28 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 22, file "/firmware/image/sbl2.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 242376 bytes transferred in 0.036s (6.50 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 12, file "/firmware/image/dsp2.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 32140366 bytes transferred in 3.376s (9.08 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 28, file "/firmware/image/dsp3.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 6334186 bytes transferred in 0.624s (9.69 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 8, file "/firmware/image/dsp1.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 2688527 bytes transferred in 0.312s (8.23 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 16, file "/data/qcks/efs1.bin"

E/kickstart(  231): 786472 bytes transferred in 0.076s (9.91 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 17, file "/data/qcks/efs2.bin"

E/kickstart(  231): 786472 bytes transferred in 0.076s (9.91 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 20, file "/data/qcks/efs3.bin"

E/kickstart(  231): 786472 bytes transferred in 0.076s (9.91 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 29, file "/data/qcks/acdb.bin"

E/kickstart(  231): 2097192 bytes transferred in 0.184s (10.89 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  231): Requested ID 6, file "/firmware/image/apps.mbn"

E/kickstart(  231): 2630368 bytes transferred in 0.304s (8.26 MBps)

E/kickstart(  231): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock

E/kickstart(  231): Sahara protocol completed

E/kickstart(  231): Removing linked list of input files

E/kickstart(  231): Removing linked list of input files

I/kickstart-qcks(  170): RetCode = 0

E/kickstart-qcks(  170): Sahara transfer completed successfully

E/kickstart-qcks(  170): Spawning efsks

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): EFS_TTY='/dev/efs_hsic_bridge'

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): Parsing 'where to save memorydump' options

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): PathToSaveFiles='/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/'

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): EFSKS parameters

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): EFS_TTY='/dev/efs_hsic_bridge'

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): ks_path='/system/bin/ks'

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): PathToSaveFiles='/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/'

I/kickstart-efsks(  232): RX_Timeout=-1

E/kickstart-efsks(  232): File '/dev/efs_hsic_bridge' was not found

E/kickstart-efsks(  232): /dev/efs_hsic_bridge does not exist.

E/kickstart-efsks(  232): RUNNING: '/system/bin/ks -m -w /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/ -p /dev/efs_hsic_bridge -t -1 -l'

E/kickstart(  235): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock

E/kickstart(  235): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock
```

can any body help me where I went wrong.

Comment: Did you add the proprietary binaries after building the first time? Can you filter logcat on error tags only and see if you have a recurring error (logcat -d -s *:E)? I assume the device is bootlooping (or the dalvik is looping) so you should see the same error more than once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is how it got solved.
First I flashed with Factory Images for Nexus Devices,(it powered up properly)
Flashed again my binaries built with instructions (boot, recovery, system and userdata). This time phone got powered up.
But I didn't get why this happened, as it got up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
fastboot flash cache cache.img
```

You should not flash cache.img unless you are doing a clean factory install. If cache.img has been flashed, attempting to boot will just show the spinning balls, and the recovery menu (boot to recovery mode and press volup-power) will show errors about not being able to mount the cache due to an invalid argument:

[image]

To fix this, select *"wipe cache partition"* from the recovery menu.

Comment: Thanks your reply is useful for those who will have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other 5.0 revisions (or higher) like android-5.0.0_r6.0.1 instead with their respective build binaries like LRX21T? Also one thing that seemed to work for me is to: 1. Flash a factory image first and then flash only the system image under product/ instead of running flashall OR 2.Replace the boot.img(which seemed to be the problematic part in my Nexus10 experience) with the boot.img from factory img and run flashall.

Comment: I built the code from this branch 'android-5.0.1_r1' as mentioned in question. I didn't get what you are trying to say in first part 'Have you tried other 5.0 revisions (or higher) like android-5.0.0_r6.0.1 instead with their respective build binaries like LRX21T?'

Comment: I was suggesting to try building and flashing a different branch like: android-5.1.0_r5 or  android-5.0.0_r6.0.1 (with their respective build binaries) which support Nexus4 according to: https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html